# Order layer in QGIS with PyQgis

Tags: pyqgis, legend, order, table-of-contents

I'm new in PyQgis. I'm looking for a code to move one layer in TOC to a specific position. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

You may want to read this [tutorial on the PyQGIS Tree Layer API (Part I & II)](http://www.lutraconsulting.co.uk/blog/2014/07/06/qgis-layer-tree-api-part-1/). This contains a part on how to move a layer within the layer TOC.